# Flask-Socketio: Managing Game Lobbies

Tags: python, flask, multiplayer, flask-socketio

This is a somewhat theoretical question; I'm still in the design stage of the app I'm trying to make.

I have a front end that supports general websockets and a back end WSGI written using Flask running Flask-SocketIO. The app is a non-realtime game, and so I need to design a system that will allow users to join short lifespan lobbies.

I'm aware of how SocketIO's rooms work, but it doesn't account for how the server will keep track of what lobbies exist, and how it can run the game logic for each lobby independently in a way that won't crash and burn if more than a few lobbies exist. It's likely that threading may be a solution, but I am not sure how that would be implemented in this context.

I'm moreso looking for pointers in the right direction and ideas rather than concrete answers; I've tried looking at the abundant examples of Flask-SocketIO chat room examples, but many of them involve storing the chat history in a database, which I want to avoid, as a lobby should simply cease to exist once everyone has left, but removing the database would be too intrusive for these examples.

TL;DR: What is the best way for a Flask-SocketIO server to track and execute game logic on different lobbies independently in a somewhat scalable and robust way?

Comment: What exactly is your game logic?

Do you want users who join a some time X after the chat room is created to have access to the chat history? If so you need a 'datastore' but not necessarily a database.

If you want the server to keep track of game what lobbies exist you'll need to manage some sort of state, and thus have some sort of 'datastore', even if its just in memory.

What's the aversion to a database?

Comment: A database in memory is fine; I want performance. Since nobody can join after the game starts, and I do not want to store much about the game after it ends, I don't want to have something I don't need slowing down the system.

Comment: ...also, my apoligies for the late reply; after a while I gave up checking this because I figured it'd be lost to the sands of time.

Comment: You definitely need a datastore. How and for how long you persist data is entirely up to you. I'd then create Models in my flask app that can access this datastore. When certain routes are called (when users fire off socket msgs from the frontend) Flask can call these Models that handle the game logic. These models can then tap into the datastore to get info on the current state of the given room.

The datastore doesn't need to be a database, it could be a text file with a json object, or just another python program storing stuff in memory etc.

Comment: The important part though is that the datastore is seperate from Flask, and will persist even if the Flask sever goes down. The Models then act as an interface to communicate with the datastore.
When I'm building proof of concepts that require state management I usuallu just store JSON objects in files. Not scalable at all but super easy and fast to get going. The key could be the chat_room id and the value could be another obj of all the data.

Comment: My recent ideas have been with multiprocessing; the Flask server handles requests and exchanges information via either a message broker or through memory to other processes that run the lobbies; I don't want the calculations to slow down handling requests. Of course, in that case the more difficult part would be the exchange of information and continuity itself. Those processes then write to persistent storage if and when needed, and otherwise just keep temporary data in memory.

Comment: Yes this is what you want to do. Note that off the shelf databases already act as a separate process and usually provide a python library to pass messages to and from the actual datastore.

Comment: Mhm, but I still wish to separate processing of game logic from handling requests, as this would otherwise hang socket requests completely under higher loads; I don't expect super high scaling, but I want to do it right the first time and have a robust foundation for this or future projects.

Comment: What I'm saying is that the solution you came up with is exactly the solution used by things like Redis, MySQL, etc. You definitely do not have to block on procedure calls to external process what ever the case and can do async writes/reads if you choose.
Often developers do have 'blocking' calls for db reads/writes but you can choose not to.
Also note that if you state is stored in memory it won't slow you're requests down. It probably won't even slow your requests down noticeably if you're writing to a file.